# How can I sandbox Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am writing an application which allow users of my application to extend it using Clojure. The Clojure is entered via a web page in the application and "evaled" to run. My question is how can I sandbox this code entered by the users so that it does not corrupt anything or call System.exit or anything like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to constrain access to code by configuring JDK level [permissions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html). Have a look at the RuntimePermission settings, there's for example a direct setting to inhibit halting the JVM (e.g. `System.exit`).

Answer (score 17):

There's a library for that. lazybot in the Clojure IRC chanel uses it. You can find it here: https://github.com/flatland/clojail

Comment: Which one of the #clojure IRC bots uses, anyway. The other one uses [clojail](https://github.com/Raynes/clojail).

Comment: This is no longer correct. sexpbot was using clj-sandbox before we wrote clojail. clojurebot never used either of the sandboxing libraries, opting for a homemade sandbox.

Comment: Updated this answer to make it factual.